# Overflow: hidden for HTML5 Video

Tags: css, html, html5-video, overflow

I am trying to hide the overflow of an HTML5 video that is wrapped in a container. However there are still scroll bars in firefox and chrome. When I try to recreate the issue in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taq50t2p/), it works fine (no scrollbars), but the same code in firefox or chrome creates a scroll and does not hide any overflow.

Any idea how I can get the overflow of an HTML5 video to hide, and why it's not working? PS. I have tried changing the position of the container to various things and have tried breaking `overflow: hidden` down to `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`

```
<div class="video_container">
<video autoplay loop controls muted="true"class="video_window">
  <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video_container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
    overflow:hidden

}

video{
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}


@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  video {
     height: 300%;
        top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  video{
     width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do the trick if you meant those annoying bars with scroll element on your DIVs. Set this to your wrapper element (e.g. .video_container)

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem for me. In Chrome and Firefox, scrolling is still enabled when I change the window size/width.

Comment: I just tested both Chrome and FF on my OS X (Mac) and it does not give me any scroll bars.. are you Windows / Linux ?

Comment: Ah, I removed position:absolute from the container and it seems to work fine! Thanks!